# Unable to create profile for firefox using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, proxy

I am using selenium 3.0.0-beta2 for Java. I am unable to set proxy. I have tried a lot of things but nothing is working. I tried the following,

```
 `String PROXY = "localhost:8080";
  DesiredCapabilities.
  Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
  proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY).setFtpProxy(PROXY).setSslProxy(PROXY)
    .setSocksProxy(PROXY);
  DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
  cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
  driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);`
```

I also tried this:

```
`FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
 profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
 profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "someproxy");
 profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 3128);
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);`
```

I am using geckodriver for firefox. I defined it as a system property like this
    `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", ".\\lib\\geckodriver.exe");`

I also found [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/97) that proxy capability is not supported yet. Is there a way to set proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have downgraded Selenium to version 2 point something and to set proxy, setPreference method worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
`ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni(); 
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("default"); 
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1); 
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "someproxy"); 
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 3128);
capabilities.setCapability("firefox_profile", profile);'
```